# Get content from complex html page?

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

I've been trying to loop through this html webpage to get the business names located within the below section of code which is nested pretty deep. All the id's are unique. I've tried using simple_html_dom but had trouble with that. I'm pretty new to PHP but an avide learner all the same, so with a point in the right direction I hope I'll crack this.

The webpage I'm trying to use is [http://yellow.co.nz/yellow+pages/funeral+home/New+Zealand?page=1&stageName=Composite+search&activeSort=name-asc&suppressMobileListings=false](http://yellow.co.nz/yellow+pages/funeral+home/New+Zealand?page=1&stageName=Composite%20search&activeSort=name-asc&suppressMobileListings=false)

```
<div class="result standard">
    <div class="resultBody"> 
        <div class="listingMain">
            <div class="vcard">
                <a class="fn openPreview">
                    <span>Biz Name</span>
```

Comment: You are looking for `DOMDocument`, not `simple_html_dom`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Robust, Mature HTML Parser for PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Answer (score 1):

You might try [Goutte](https://github.com/fabpot/Goutte) and do something like

```
use Goutte\Client;

$client = new Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://yellow.co.nz/yellow+pages/funeral+home/New+Zealand?page=1&stageName=Composite+search&activeSort=name-asc&suppressMobileListings=false');

$businessNames = array();
$crawler->filter('vcard > fn > span')->each(function($node, $i){
  $businessNames[] = $node->text();   
});
```

Comment: Downloaded Goutte but I'm getting error " Fatal error: Class 'Goutte\Client' not found in D:\wamp\www\GrabListings\index.php on line 13"

Comment: Sorry my mistake forgot to require_once('goutte.phar');

Comment: Can you combine both id's and class in this statement: `$crawler->filter("DSContents > mainContent > searchResultsForm > resultsCont > cbParent > result > resultBody > listingMain > vcard > fn > span")->each(function($node, $i){
            $businessNames[] = $node->text();   
            });`

Answer (score 0):

When I have had similar problems in the past (digging through an arbitrary hierarchy to my target nodes), I found XPath to be the most helpful solution:

[PHP DOM Xpath documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)

It allows you to use a very straightforward XPath query to immediately target the nodes of interest.